# Error in stats::runif(10) : object 'C_runif' not found

Tags: r

this is my error

Error in stats::runif (10) : object 'C_runif' not found

how would I solve this?

Comment: We need to see the complete code that generated the error. But it looks like there is a variable, `C_runif`, that was not defined.

Comment: @neilfws, wouldn't that be related to the contents of `stats::runif` that is merely `.Call(C_runif, n, min, max)`?

Comment: Very possibly! Seeing that complete code would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only reproduce that error by trying to call the internals of `stats::runif` manually:

```r
stats::runif
# function (n, min = 0, max = 1) 
# .Call(C_runif, n, min, max)
# <bytecode: 0x0000000018bc9498>
# <environment: namespace:stats>

.Call(C_runif, 5, 1, 10)
# Error: object 'C_runif' not found
```

The issue is that `C_runif` (as happens in many packages) is not exported. You can work around this with the use of `:::`, though this is discouraged in general (non-exported functions can and do change their interface, though perhaps not frequently in the `stats` base package). If you *must*, then you can do:

```r
.Call(stats:::C_runif, 5, 1, 10)
# [1] 6.977998 7.935927 9.604516 5.198580 1.479527
```

However, this buys you *very little* over using `stats::runif` itself, since it is merely a wrapper that does nothing but that specific call.